# Following Michael Hartl cht 3 - getting rails welcome page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Just been setting up the testing in Chapter 3 on MH's tutorial and ran into issue - when I restarted the rails server I just get the Rails Welcome page - I have zero idea why or where to find out why - anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-28 11:43:12 +0100
    Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)``
```

Comment: You can specify what Rails should route '/' to with the root method. You should use `root :to => "pages#home"` is the default route, i.e. when you go to "yourdomain.com/" it routes to the home action in the pages controller

Comment: @DeeptiKakade Post this as an answer (with some more detail) so that the user can close their question if it is right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify root in routes.rb. The `root :to controller#action`  is a rails route that says the default address for your site.

When you use root :to rails 3 automatically creates the helper methods root_url and root_path for referencing your application root.

If you specify root in routes.rb for example:

```
root :to => "pages#index"
```

It means whenever you hit your application domain it will show you index page of page controller.